# How to discover all sites in Multi-Geo tenants using SharePoint REST API

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

We have a multi-geo tenant and we want to get all Site Collections across all locations.
Currently, we try to use the next SharePoint REST API endpoint:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:sts_site+NOT+WebTemplate:SPSPERS'&trimduplicates=false&selectproperties='Path'"
```

However, it returns me a list of sites in the default Geo-location.
What should I use to list sites based on other available Geo-Locations?

Comment: Is the query provided here useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/multigeo-discovery ? URLs from all geo-locations are retrieved

Comment: The MS Graph request beta/sites?filter=siteCollection/root%20ne%20null&select=webUrl,siteCollection just gives you the root site for each Geo-Location